# How to convert input list into an integer list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, delimiter

I'm solving a problem and the user will give the input in this pattern-

```
[5,10,15,20]
```

Since this is an input given by the user, it is a string. I want to convert these numbers into integer and store them in a list.

I tried using the following code -

```
import re
mystr=input()
mylist=list(re.split('[ |, |] ',mystr))
print(mylist)
```

The output is:

```
['[5,10,15,20]']
```

Why isn't re.split() splitting that input properly?
I want the output to be a list of integers which were entered by the user.

I apologise if the question is a duplicate. I'm a newbie to python as well as to stackoverflow.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `[int(x) for x in re.split(",",mystr[1:-1])]` would do it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a string to its python equivalent:

```
>>> import ast
>>> mystr = '[5,10,15,20]'
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(mystr)
>>> x
[5, 10, 15, 20]
```

`eval` is much more general than `ast.literal_eval`.  But, `ast.literal_eval` is much safer to use.

#### Documentation

From the [python online docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> **ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)**
>  Safely evaluate an expression node or
>   a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string
>   or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets,
>   booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.
>
> Changed in version 3.2: Now allows bytes and set literals.

#### Working with re

Let's slightly modify the regex:

```
>>> mystr = '[5,10,15,20]'
>>> list(re.split('[ |, |]+', mystr))
['[5', '10', '15', '20]']
```

To get rid of the leading and trailing square brackets:

```
>>> list(re.split('[ |, |]+', mystr.strip('[]')))
['5', '10', '15', '20']
```

The above gives us a list of strings.  To convert them to integers:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in re.split('[ |, |]+', mystr.strip('[]'))]
[5, 10, 15, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why isn't re.split() working in my code? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Safer in what way? What are the risks if we use eval?

Comment: @AyushGoyal `eval` will run arbitrary code.  That means it may delete or overwrite files on your system, etc.

Comment: @AyushGoyal I just added to the answer code (less general) that worked with `re` to get to the same answer.

Comment: Nice job, literal_eval is new to me, thanks@John1024

Answer (score 2):

If you trust the user enough(Only if he/she is you yourself), 
You can use, But becareful:

```
mylist = eval("[5,10,15,20]")
```

a safer solution(No error handling):

```
mystr = mystr.strip('[')
mystr = mystr.strip(']')
mylist = [int(i) for i in mystr.split(',')]
```